# Web 8 - Context Engine Catridge - Creating Device database Issue

Tags: web8, context-engine

I'm trying to create device database on my Web 8 environment as per the [doc](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-8E5F4BCD-E975-43A1-9884-BDD73D232195). While running the updateRepository.ps1 cmdlet, experiencing below error:

```
PS D:\SDLWeb_MicroServices\context\bin> .\updateRepository.ps1
HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (invalid authorizatio
n specification - not found: SA)
HHH000319: Could not get database metadata
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (invalid authorization specification
 - not found: SA)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549) ~[commons-
dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.
4]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConne
ctionProviderImpl.java:139) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConne
ctionHelper.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9
.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:203) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9
.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:522) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.ja
r:4.3.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar
:4.3.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar
:4.3.9.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.
java:372) [spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:4
54) [spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:43
9) [spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowi
reCapableBeanFactory.java:1633) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireC
apableBeanFactory.java:1570) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCap
ableBeanFactory.java:539) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapab
leBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) [spri
ng-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegis
try.java:230) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) [spring
-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-b
eans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBe
anFactory.java:1120) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanF
actory.java:1044) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFac
tory.java:942) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.injec
t(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) [spring-bean
s-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(A
utowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCap
ableBeanFactory.java:1210) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCap
ableBeanFactory.java:537) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapab
leBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) [spri
ng-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegis
try.java:230) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) [spring
-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-b
eans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBe
anFactory.java:1120) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanF
actory.java:1044) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFac
tory.java:942) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.injec
t(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) [spring-bean
s-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(A
utowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCap
ableBeanFactory.java:1210) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCap
ableBeanFactory.java:537) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapab
leBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) [spri
ng-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegis
try.java:230) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) [spring
-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:217) [spring-b
eans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:
350) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:
331) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:968) [
spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at com.sdl.context.engine.repository.ContextRepositoryManager.initManager(ContextRepositoryManager.java:243) [cw
d_engine-8.1.1-1034.jar:8.1.1-1034]
        at com.sdl.context.engine.repository.ContextRepositoryManager.main(ContextRepositoryManager.java:73) [cwd_engine
-8.1.1-1034.jar:8.1.1-1034]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: invalid authorization specification - not found: SA
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38) ~[commons-d
bcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582) ~[commons-db
cp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556) ~[commons-dbcp-1
.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545) ~[commons-
dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: invalid authorization specification - not found: SA
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        at org.hsqldb.rights.UserManager.get(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        at org.hsqldb.rights.UserManager.getUser(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        at org.hsqldb.Database.connect(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
        ... 58 common frames omitted
HHH000299: Could not complete schema update
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (invalid authorization specification
 - not found: SA)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549) ~[commons-
dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.
4]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConne
ctionProviderImpl.java:139) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConne
ctionHelper.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9
.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:203) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9
.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:522) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.ja
r:4.3.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar
:4.3.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar
:4.3.9.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.
java:372) [spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:4
54) [spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:43
9) [spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowi
reCapableBeanFactory.java:1633) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireC
apableBeanFactory.java:1570) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCap
ableBeanFactory.java:539) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapab
leBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) [spri
ng-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegis
try.java:230) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) [spring
-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-b
eans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBe
anFactory.java:1120) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanF
actory.java:1044) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFac
tory.java:942) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.injec
t(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) [spring-bean
s-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(A
utowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCap
ableBeanFactory.java:1210) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCap
ableBeanFactory.java:537) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapab
leBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) [spri
ng-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegis
try.java:230) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) [spring
-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
```

My machine IP is white-listed and running powershell as an administrator. I'm wondering what I'm missing? Appreciate your inputs!

Comment: Not that this helps in anyway, but I'm seeing the exact same error on an 8.2 (cloud) release - we're looking into it.

Comment: Thanks @NunoLinhares. Kindly keep posted on your findings.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have permissions to create the repository folder in the `..\services` folder?]

As per followup comment, try removing repository folder.

Comment: I could see repository folder created successfully in ..\services folder but above error is still occurring. Also I'm running with administrator user, So I presume it has required permissions.

Comment: Same here - also running as a local admin.

Comment: And I assume there's no existing set of `repository/sdl-context-repository-*` files in this folder already?

Comment: @Bengineer, thanks for your suggestion, removing the repository folder and trying again with updateRepository.ps1worked!! Could get the device database created successfully now. Not sure why it didnt work at the first go, as there was no repository folder at the beginning. Anyways, issue seems to be resolved, pls update your answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: "pls update your answer, I'll accept it!" -> And you never did...